# Bootstrap 3 and 4 tooltip error TypeError: $(...).tooltip is not a function happending sometimes

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-tooltip

The error does not happen all the time, if it does it will appear in console and the tooltip feature will not work.

Every 10 refreshes, it may appear 1 or twice. The rest of the time the tooltip function works perfectly.

Happens more often with jquery 2+, jquery 3+ less often.

Comment: Are your files referenced in correct order? Do you somehow have two versions of jQuery loaded?

Comment: Do you have async or defer on any of the javascript files?

Comment: Yes, problem is related to setting the right async and/or defer attributes. The current order that works for me now is:

1. jquery.js
2. tether.js (bootstrap 4 only) with defer
3. bootstrap.js with defer